# The error "Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice" occurred when calculate modulo of matrix using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

As the code below, addition/subtraction/multiplication/division of the matrix works fine.
Only the modulo operation gives the error.

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = tf.fill([2, 2], 3.)
    b = tf.fill([2, 2], 2.)
    # print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
    print(a + b)
    print(a - b)
    print(a * b)
    print(a / b)
    print(a // b)
    print(a % b)

result =>
C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\python.exe D:/Repo/workspace/PycharmProjects/tensorflow_demo/process/calc.py 
tf.Tensor(
[[5. 5.]
 [5. 5.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[6. 6.]
 [6. 6.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1.5 1.5]
 [1.5 1.5]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Repo\workspace\PycharmProjects\tensorflow_demo\process\calc.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(a % b)
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Thinkpad\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 7209, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: {{function_node __wrapped__FloorMod_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} JIT compilation failed. [Op:FloorMod]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone tell me why and how to solve it, please?

I have tried setting XLA_FLAGS=--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8", but it did not work.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with GPU setup in your system. Please refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57055) as a reference which might help you to solve this error.